Minecraft Forge 1.20.1 Mod animation problem
First, I want to mention that this is my first post here, so I apologize in advance if I don’t express my problem clearly. I’ve been stuck on this issue for a long time and really need help.
Objective:
My goal is to link an animation I created in BlockBench to my custom plane entity in Minecraft.
Current Result:
The plane appears in the world, but no animation is running.
Expected Result:
The plane's rotor should be spinning.
Project Structure Overview:
Here's a simplified view of my project structure:
+---main
    +---java
        +---fr
            +---Thorid4n
                +---Planes
                    ForPlanes.java
                    +---block
                        ModBlocks.java
                    +---entity
                        ModEntities.java
                        +---animations
                            ModAnimationDefinitions.java
                        +---client
                            ModModelLayers.java
                            YellowPlaneModel.java
                            YellowPlaneRenderer.java
                        +---custom
                            RhinoEntity.java
                            YellowPlaneEntity.java
                    +---event
                        ModEventBusEvents.java
                        ModEvents.java

Classes Involved:
1. YellowPlaneEntity
This class handles the plane entity mechanics. Below are the relevant parts related to the animation:
public class YellowPlaneEntity extends Entity {

    private static final EntityDataAccessor<Boolean> IS_FLYING = SynchedEntityData.defineId(YellowPlaneEntity.class, EntityDataSerializers.BOOLEAN);
    public final AnimationState propellerAnimationState = new AnimationState();
    private int propellerAnimationTimeout = 0;

    // Other fields and methods...

    private void setupAnimationStates() {
        if(this.propellerAnimationTimeout == 0) {
            this.propellerAnimationTimeout = this.random.nextInt(10) + 5;
            this.propellerAnimationState.start(this.tickCount);
        } else {
            this.propellerAnimationTimeout--;
        }

        if(!this.isFlying()) {
            this.propellerAnimationState.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        super.tick();

        if(this.level().isClientSide()) {
            setupAnimationStates();
        }

        // Other logic...
    }
}

2. YellowPlaneRenderer
This class is pretty standard; it’s used to render the entity. The setupAnim method is called within it:
public class YellowPlaneRenderer extends EntityRenderer<YellowPlaneEntity> {

    // Other fields and methods...

    @Override
    public void render(YellowPlaneEntity entity, float entityYaw, float partialTicks, PoseStack poseStack,
                       net.minecraft.client.renderer.MultiBufferSource buffer, int packedLight) {
        poseStack.pushPose();
        
        // System.out.println("YellowPlaneRenderer render called");
        
        this.model.setupAnim(entity, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Rendering logic...
    }
}

3. YellowPlaneModel
This class was generated using BlockBench to define the model. The key part is the setupAnim method:
public class YellowPlaneModel<T extends Entity> extends HierarchicalModel<T> {

    // Other fields and methods...

    @Override
    public void setupAnim(T entity, float limbSwing, float limbSwingAmount, float ageInTicks, float netHeadYaw, float headPitch) {
        System.out.println("Animation setup called! Age in Ticks: " + ((YellowPlaneEntity) entity).tickCount);
        
        this.root().getAllParts().forEach(ModelPart::resetPose);

        this.animate(((YellowPlaneEntity) entity).propellerAnimationState, ModAnimationDefinitions.PROPELLER_ROTATION, ((YellowPlaneEntity) entity).tickCount, 1.0f);
        System.out.println("Current propeller rotation: " + this.Pales.xRot);
    }
}

This method is correctly called when the plane is in the world, but the ageInTicks does not seem to increment as expected.
4. ModAnimationDefinitions
This class defines the animation, which is directly exported from BlockBench:
public class ModAnimationDefinitions {
    public static final AnimationDefinition PROPELLER_ROTATION = AnimationDefinition.Builder.withLength(1f).looping()
        .addAnimation("Pales",
            new AnimationChannel(AnimationChannel.Targets.ROTATION,
                new Keyframe(0f, KeyframeAnimations.degreeVec(0f, 0f, 0f), AnimationChannel.Interpolations.LINEAR),
                new Keyframe(1f, KeyframeAnimations.degreeVec(0f, 0f, 90f), AnimationChannel.Interpolations.LINEAR)))
        .build();
}

Issue Description:
Although the tickCount is incrementing correctly, the rotor’s rotation (this.Pales.xRot) remains unchanged. I’ve verified that the setupAnim method is called, and the animation is applied, but the rotation does not update as expected.
My Question:
What could be causing the animation to not properly apply the rotation to the model? Is there something I might be missing when linking the BlockBench animation to my entity?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to modify my YellowPlaneModel -> setupAnim method to do the animation by "hand" doing :
public void setupAnim(T entity, float limbSwing, float limbSwingAmount, float ageInTicks, float netHeadYaw, float headPitch) {
    this.root().getAllParts().forEach(ModelPart::resetPose);
        this.Pales.xRot += 0.1f;

With that the rotor was doing what I wanted it to do but I realy would like to use the animation class to be able to do more complicated animation trough BlockBench in the futur
